# Why does my bank wants me to send them a W-8BEN if I live in the US?

Tags: bank-account, form-w-8-ben

I have a bank account in Bank of America and they are adamant that I should send file a W-8BEN, even if I live in the US and I am taxable in the US. I already told them about that but they keep insisting that I should (falsely) state that I'm not a US person for tax purposes. They keep sending letters and telling me over over the phone or in person to do that. I wonder if I'm the wrong one here.

Comment: You say "_I live in the US_", but are you "_a U.S. citizen or other U.S. person, including a resident alien individual_"? If you _are_, then from the second bullet-point of [W-8BEN](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf) (PDF), you _shouldn't_ use that form. Presumably, though, if you don't fall in that category, you should.

Comment: @TripeHound Yes, I am a U.S. person. However I can't understand why is my bank insisting to me to falsely claim that I'm not. Do they have some wrong information about me? I called them to rectify, but they still want to to submit a fraudulent W8-BEN.